# How can non-moderators suggest a better duplicate target without flagging?

Tags: support, exact-duplicates

I posted a flag to [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/45563/is-this-iq-map-valid) suggesting a better duplicate target. The response I got was "helpful - You are able to edit in additional dupe targets". However, when I tried clicking on the "edit" link, I don't see a place to put in duplicate targets.

How do I suggest a better duplicate target without flagging?

(BTW - it'd be a terrible shame if this question got deleted. So don't do that!)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply clicked the wrong edit link! Easy mistake to make, it's not all that obvious unless you know it's there

[image]

Once clicked, you can use the "Add" button to add as many *other* duplicates as you like

[image]

However, it appear you need to be a gold tag holder to access this feature: [Gold tag-badge holders and moderators can now edit duplicate links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291824/gold-tag-badge-holders-and-moderators-can-now-edit-duplicate-links)

Comment: It doesn’t appear on my mobile phone. Doesn’t seem to appear on desktop either.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm you could also scroll to the bottom of the page on your phone and choose "full site" and see if it shows up that way.

Comment: Yep, just did that.

Comment: It appears you need to be a gold tag holder to access this feature. Whoever marked your flag as helpful may not have realised this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291824/gold-tag-badge-holders-and-moderators-can-now-edit-duplicate-links